# XAML VisualState AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth change programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, visualstatemanager

I have some VisualStates and I want to Change the `AdaptiveTrigger` `MinWindowWidth` in the Code behind in a if statment.

VisualState:

```
<VisualState x:Name="VisualState">
     <VisualState.StateTriggers>
         <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1100"/>
     </VisualState.StateTriggers>
     ....
</VisualState>
```

and in the Code behind it should look like this:

```
if (Something == true)
{
     VisualState1.SetValue(AdaptiveTrigger.MinWindowWidthProperty, 1370);
}
```

I don't know why but it doesn't work and so I hope you can help me.

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_ - What do you expect to happen?

Comment: it should change the VisualState Trigger but it doesn't, it uses the  AdaptiveTrigger defined in the XAML even if the if statemante is true.

Comment: You have to name the `AdaptiveTrigger` itself, not the `VisualState`. That should do the job.

Comment: thank you this solved the Problem if you post it as an answer I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refering to the `VisualState` itself won't do the job. The property you are refering to belongs to the `AdaptiveTrigger`.

```
<VisualState x:Name="VisualState">
  <VisualState.StateTriggers>
    <!-- For better reference in code behind, include VisualState name -->
    <AdaptiveTrigger x:Name="TriggerOfVisualState"
                     MinWindowWidth="1100"/>
  </VisualState.StateTriggers>
 ....
</VisualState>
```

**Please note:**
The way you are setting the new value acts like setting an attached property.
You should only set them like this, if the property is actually an attached property (e.g. `Grid.Row`).
Otherwise use the direct property accessor:

```
TriggerOfVisualState.MinWindowWidth = 1370;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<VisualState>
     <VisualState.StateTriggers>
         <AdaptiveTrigger x:Name="MyTrigger" MinWindowWidth="1100"/>
     </VisualState.StateTriggers>
     ....
</VisualState>
```

and code-behind:

```
MyTrigger.MinWindowWidth = 1370;
```

If you use MVVM or some other data binding, you can also use `{Binding myMinWidth}` for the `MinWindowWidth` property value.